Does anyone know what this Apache HTTPD rule is?
I was going through the rewrite rules and saw this:
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=permanant]

I checked Apache's RewriteRule Flags list,
but cannot find any info there.
Is it an alias to 301?

A more useful reference would be alongside the one you quoted, at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=permanant]


There's an error in this line (permanent is misspelt), but assuming that's a typo in the question rather than in your Apache configuration, here's what the line says:

RewriteRule - it's a URL rewriting rule from mod_rewrite
^(.*)/$ - match the RE that describes anything at all, ending with /, and remember everything as $1 except that trailing /
$1 - if found, prepare to use the match group we just found (i.e. the original URL without a trailing /)
[R=permanent] - send a Redirect instruction to the web browser tagged as permanent, i.e. HTTP 301

In other words, as pointed out in a comment, it will redirect the web browser from any URL path on this server ending with a slash to one without.

Put more succinctly, it will redirect from e. g. https://www.example.com/directory/ to https://www.example.com/directory.

@DopeGhoti thank you!

@ChrisDavies "permanant" is an actual rewrite rule in our config (just started on the job and was going through the existing config)

In addition to Chris's answer, a full explanation of the following regular expression ^(.*)/$ $1: 
^ is identified as the beginning of the string.
() used to create a capture group 
(.*) This means match anything 
$ This means the end of the string 
$1 refers to the first capture in the group 
when you combine them you will get capture matches for any URL that ends with a slash (/) then take the first one.
